# How to handle drawables in a Flutter plugin project

Tags: android, flutter, flutter-plugin

I'm trying to create a Flutter plugin.

Any attempts to use a drawable on the Android side fails (not found exception).

```
R.drawable.myicon
```

Or

```
context.getResources().getIdentifier("icon", "id", context.getPackageName())
```

I have an icon.png file in both the android/src/main/res/drawable and the other dpi specific drawable folders.

How can I use drawable files in a Flutter plugin?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Silly me, the answer was:

```
context.getResources().getIdentifier("icon", "drawable", context.getPackageName())
```

Instead of

```
context.getResources().getIdentifier("icon", "id", context.getPackageName())
```